# Dependency Injection in CLI Main, object is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, command-line-interface

In my CLI Main I need a object of my MonDbBusinessComponent class.
I wrote the code below, but my object is still null.
What's wrong? How to do it right?

```
public static IMonDbBusinessComponent monDbBusinessComponent { get; set; }
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var collection = new ServiceCollection();
    collection.AddScoped<IMonDbRepository, MonDbRepository>();
    ServiceProvider appServiceProvider = GetServiceProvider();
    monDbBusinessComponent = appServiceProvider.GetService<IMonDbBusinessComponent>();
```

Comment: It's hard to tell, because your example doesn't show what `GetServiceProvider()` is doing. It's likely null because `IMonDbBusinessComponent` isn't in the service collection.

Comment: Is your program a console app? You may not need dependency injection with a service collection at all. Can you simply do `new MonDbBusinessComponent(new MonDbRepository`?

Answer (score 1):

you never registered your IMonDbBusinessComponent.

```
collection.AddScoped<IMonDbBusinessComponent, MonDbBusinessComponent>();
```

Comment: Thats right. I register a other class.(Repository instead of BusinessComponent.) But now after adding BusinessComponent my object is still null.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, it was not possible to see in my published coded. The BusinessComponent uses Repository and first I needed to register the Repository with it's arguments and then register the BusinessComponent.
Also at the BusinessComonent I needed to use the Interface instead of the class.

```
public MonDbBusinessComponent(IMonDbRepository monDbRepository){...}

collection.AddScoped<IMonDbRepository>(ServiceProvider =>
{
    string createMetaDataRecordFunctionName = Configurations.Get(LocalConfiguration, "CreateMetaDataRecordFunctionName");
    string conDbDataRecordFunctionName = Configurations.Get(LocalConfiguration, "ConDbDataRecordFunctionName");
    return new MonDbRepository(metaDataConnection, createMetaDataRecordFunctionName, conDbDataRecordFunctionName);
});
collection.AddScoped<IMonDbBusinessComponent, MonDbBusinessComponent>();
```

Thanks for all support!